# SSIS run vbs from another server

Tags: ssis, windows-server-2012-r2

We are planning to build two server.

AS1: Windows Server 2012 Datacenter + MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. This will be mainly for ETL (SSIS).

BS1: Windows Server that contain other data sources.

My question is can we run a job from AS1 but the sources files are from BS1?

Explaining the task:

AS1 - Create SSIS ETL Task
BS1 - Some data sources files. It will be an excel that contain some vbs

Process:
AS1 execute the ETL job though SSIS, it loaded up the excel and run the vbs from BS1.

I am not sure is this doable but one thing I want to say is that this still on planning stage so I am welcome for any other suggestions. Please do not post any code here as I am more interest about am I on the right direction and which direction should I go if I am not on the right track.

Side note:
I am thinking will this doable if AS1 mapped network drive (BS1)?

A little more background information. We want to separate the workload as BS1 will connect to 5-6 database (may be a few more) and generate some files such as Excel and other kind of reports. These excels will contain some vbs that help to organise the report structures. AS1 will have quite a lot of different automate scheduling for executing the ETL jobs though SSIS.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Not sure why people will keep downvoting questions. I am just here asking am I on the right track or is there have a better suggestion. Didn't ask for code or step by step instruction kind of stuffs. Please let me know why you down vote it and so I can avoid having the same mistake again. Or just simply all questions here will be treat like student asking for homework answer?

Comment: Can you share excel files to AS1 server? maybe get it via ftp?. If you want AS1 do all the SSIS work you should have the data in there somewhat. By the way some users want questions be built as they do resulting in arbitrary down votes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as AS1 can see BS1 on the network, you can run a job on AS1 that will use data sources on BS1.

Comment: Tested that part and this lead to another problem. How can I tell BS1 do the job? I mean the execution. As for now, AS1 only using BS1 datasources. I want to use ssis on AS1 and tell BS1 to do the actual execution

Comment: New thought is AS1 > ssis > powershell > BS2 > run xlsm (example) . Or I should install ssis on BS1 as well?

Comment: If you want BS1 to act as the "engine" for some reason, then yes, you need to install SSIS on it.  Why not do the job on AS1?   If you run the job on BS1, what do you even need AS1 for?

Comment: Want to share workload. We will extract 1-300k records pre day. AS1 will do the etl part and extract record to excel(not just one excel)  BS1 will get the excel and run some formula/vbs. So not sure which is the best method for BS1.

Comment: Me either, I'm not an excel/vbs expert, and that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Flow changed and so this question nolonger need an answer.